# Join 2 tables: one data table and one table of statut and get statut with no entrie

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT c.Show_Code, req.Statut_ID, COUNT(req.Statut_ID) 'Count'
FROM [Case] c
JOIN Request req ON req.Case_Number = c.Number
GROUP BY c.Show_Code, req.Statut_ID
```

The result is:

```
Show_Code   Statut_ID   Count
564900          2         1
568127          2         1
```

And I have this statut table (Ref_RequestStatut)

```
ID   Name
1    Test
2    Test2
```

How can I get this result:

```
Show_Code   Statut_ID   Count
564900          1         0
564900          2         1
568127          1         0
568127          2         1
```

I want all the statut, even those which have no value?

Thank

Comment: What is the structure of your Case table - can you post it as well?

Comment: `Case` contains Number and Show_Code columns

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later:

```
WITH counted AS (
  SELECT c.Show_Code, req.Statut_ID, COUNT(req.Statut_ID) 'Count'
  FROM [Case] c
  JOIN Request req ON req.Case_Number = c.Number
  GROUP BY c.Show_Code, req.Statut_ID
),
showcodes AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT Show_Code
  FROM counted
)
SELECT
  s.Show_Code,
  r.ID AS Statut_ID,
  Count = ISNULL(c.Count, 0)
FROM showcodes s
  CROSS JOIN Ref_RequestStatut r
  LEFT JOIN counted c ON s.Show_Code = c.Show_Code AND r.ID = c.Statut_ID
ORDER BY 
  s.Show_Code,
  r.ID
```

Comment: I made one minor mistake: `r.Statut_ID` should actually be `r.ID` (fixed). Other than that, this should work. I tested it by replacing the `counted` subselect (which is the OP's first query) with its hard-coded result, and adding another CTE for `Ref_RequestStatut` (as a hard-coded rowset too). `showcodes` is all the distinct `Show_Code` values that are returned by the `counted` subquery. It is cross-joined with `Ref_RequestStatut` resulting in all the combinations of Show Codes from `counted` with Statut IDs from the ref. table. What is missing now is only the counts (`left join counted`).